# Enum of GUID's/Guid interop

Tags: c#, interop

I'm doing some interop and need to pass some GUID's. Is there a way to add a GUID attribute to an enum value and when it is marshalled it has the appropriate value?

Basically I'm trying to convert the code

```
#if !defined( STATIC_KSDATAFORMAT_SUBTYPE_PCM )
#define STATIC_KSDATAFORMAT_SUBTYPE_PCM\
    DEFINE_WAVEFORMATEX_GUID(WAVE_FORMAT_PCM)
DEFINE_GUIDSTRUCT("00000001-0000-0010-8000-00aa00389b71", KSDATAFORMAT_SUBTYPE_PCM);
#define KSDATAFORMAT_SUBTYPE_PCM DEFINE_GUIDNAMED(KSDATAFORMAT_SUBTYPE_PCM)
#endif
```

(and several other similar ones)

and use them in an enum so I can specify the appropriate subtype format easily. Obviously I could probably just use a dictionary or some other similar method but I would like to make it as transparent as possible.

It would be nice to do something like

```
enum MyGuids : Guid
{
  Guid1 = GUID("...") or just "..."
}
```

I can use a class/struct instead

```
static class MyGuids
{
    public static Guid flag1 = new Guid("9ED54F84-A89D-4fcd-A854-44251E925F09");
}
```

But the only problem here is there is no way to relate the Guid in unmanaged structure to this class. It's specified as Guid and if I replaced it with MyGuids then it won't be a Guid any more. e.g., I lose type safety since any guid can end up in the field and not just the ones from MyGuid.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Guids are structures in .NET, they are too large to fit in a simple value type by a factor of two.  Sounds to me that you need a structure member initialized.  That's going to need an assignment statement in your code.  The const will work just fine for this.  There is otherwise no way to get the compiler to do it automatically.

```
  var sound = new foo();
  sound.waveFormat = MyGuids.flag1;
  // etc..
```

Comment: I don't think you understand the problem. It is not an assignment issue but a value restriction problem. Enums are useful because they restrict assignable values and have meaningful representation. I'm looking for the same. Using a static class/struct gets the meaningful representation but doesn't restrict the assignable values. This leads to the possibility of using the wrong values. It's not a huge deal but one should be able to do it... of course just another thing MS forgot to implement.

Comment: Stuffing a guid in an enum isn't going to happen, a 128 bit pig doesn't fit in a 64 bit poke.  This isn't the right place to discuss what MSFT should do or forgot, post feature requests to connect.microsoft.com

Comment: um, no but that doesn't mean there isn't some way to use reflection and metadata to potentially solve the problem. In any case I see we are not going to get a solution here.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?

```
void Main()
{
    var dog = MyValues.Dog.ToId();  
    var cat = MyValues.Cat.ToId();  
    var bird = MyValues.Bird.ToId();    
}

public enum MyValues
{ 
    Dog,
    Cat,
    Bird
}

public static class Functions
{
    public static Guid ToId(this MyValues value)
    {
        switch (value)
        {
            case MyValues.Dog:
                return Guid.Parse("6d139d6a-2bfa-466d-a9a5-c6e82f9abf51");
            case MyValues.Cat:
                return Guid.Parse("AA139d6a-2bfa-466d-a9a5-c6e82f9abf51");
            case MyValues.Bird:
                return Guid.Parse("BB139d6a-2bfa-466d-a9a5-c6e82f9abf51");
            default:
                throw new InvalidDataException();
        }
    }
}
```